# populating dropdownlist based on another in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have this in my html

```
 function populate(myop) {
        var selection = myop.options[myop.selectedIndex].text;

        PopulateTaskddl(selection);
    }

  <select id="ddljobname_In" name="cpname_job" onchange="populate(this.value)" style="margin-left: 10px; color: Black;">
                </select>
```

it gives me error  says " Populate is undefined ..

Any help ?

Comment: Put the script after the HTML

Comment: Is your `populate` function inside inside a `<script></script>` tag?

Comment: yes.Issue is resolved. Thanks @tymeJV

Comment: No. :)  it actually didn't give an error like that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put your JavaScript function in script tags, so that your browser knows that it's JavaScript, not HTML.

JS is not HTML and you have to declare so. You might start with some tutorials and learn how to use HTML, CSS, JavaScript & co. before posting on a Q&A platform like StackOverflow.

```
<script>
    function populate(myop) {
        var selection = myop.options[myop.selectionIndex].text;
        PopulateTaskddl(selection);
    }
<script>
<select id="ddljobname_In" name="cpname_job" onchange="populate(this.value)" style="margin-left: 10px; color: Black;">
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<select id="ddljobname_In" name="cpname_job" onchange="populate(this)" style="margin-left: 10px; color: Black;">
</select>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function populate(myop) {
        var selection = myop.options[myop.selectedIndex].text;
        PopulateTaskddl(selection);
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You shouldn't. It's not your solution... =)

Comment: Yeah you actually right  around 100 percent .. Thanks @tymeJV

Comment: Can anyone do it then :)